# KeyError: 'ir.model.data'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to migrate a v14 app to v15 and I'm getting this error. Can you guys help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
r = d[key]   
File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__ a = self.d[obj]

**KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData._xmlid_lookup at 0x7fcbb39103a0>, 'web.assets_backend')**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 680, in
_tag_root
    f(rec)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 658, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 567, in
_tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 663, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 669, in
model_id_get
    return self.env['ir.model.data']._xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str,
raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line
1943, in _xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
    return self._xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]   File "<decorator-gen-35>", line 2, in _xmlid_lookup   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line
1936, in _xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid) ValueError: External ID not found in the system:
web.assets_backend

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line
237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 535, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1347, in
call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/auto/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1335, in
_call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 464, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 451, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "<decorator-gen-70>", line 2, in button_immediate_install   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line
74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line
483, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py",
line 600, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 474, in
load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 363, in
load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in
load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 69, in
load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 745, in
convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 811, in
convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 731, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 693, in
_tag_root
    raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % ( Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 643, in
_handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/custom/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in
_handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:7, somewhere inside
<data name="Quick Reservation Summary"
inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/hotel_reservation/static/src/css/room_summary.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/hotel_reservation/static/src/js/hotel_room_summary.js"/>
        </xpath>
    </data>
```

Comment: [How to Manage Asset Bundles in Odoo 15](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-manage-asset-bundles-in-odoo-15) in odoo 15 we don't use xpath to add js or qweb templates we do it in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solve this issue just updating the default apps.
Go to Apps and in the apps search bar filter as shown Below: (Apps, Extra and Installed)
[Filter Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTyUo.png)

Then upgrade the base app (Kernel for Oddo)

Problem solved.